# Как запросить , разрешена ли на устройстве "Установка из небезопасных источников"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как запросить , разрешена ли на устройстве "Установка из небезопасных источников"?
Если возможно пример кода.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вкратце, чтобы пользователи `с Android API 25 и ниже` могли устанавливать из небезопасных источников, они должны включить параметр "Неизвестные источники" в настройках. [1](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/)

> Примечание: Когда пользователи пытаются установить неизвестное
>   приложение на устройстве под управлением Android 7.1.1 (уровень 25
>   API) или ниже, система иногда показывает диалоговое окно которое
>   спрашивает пользователя, независимо от того, хотят ли они позволить
>   только одного конкретного неизвестного приложения для установки. Почти
>   во всех случаях пользователи должны позволить только одно неизвестное
>   приложение установки в то время, если параметр доступен для них. [1](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/)

```
boolean isNonPlayAppAllowed = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) == 1;

if (!isNonPlayAppAllowed) {
    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS));
}
```

[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333602/programatically-find-whether-installing-from-unknown-sources-is-allowed)

---

А для того, чтобы пользователи `с Android API 26 и выше`, могли устанавливать из небезопасных источников **необходимо предоставить разрешение**. [1](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/)

Добавить в `manifest.xml` [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446269/auto-download-and-install-apk-in-android-o)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Затем самое основное: [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446269/auto-download-and-install-apk-in-android-o)

```
private void checkIsAndroidO() {  
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {  
    boolean result = getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls();  
    if (result) {  
      installApk();
    } else {  
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES}, INSTALL_PACKAGES_REQUESTCODE);  
    }  
  } else {
    installApk();  
  }  
}

@Override  
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {  
  super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

  switch (requestCode) {  
    case INSTALL_PACKAGES_REQUESTCODE:  
      if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {  
        installApk();  
      } else {  
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES);  
        startActivityForResult(intent, GET_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES);  
      }  
    break;  
  }  
}

@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

  switch (requestCode) {  
    case GET_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES:  
      checkIsAndroidO();  
      break;  

    default:  
      break;  
  }  
}
```

---

Источники: [1](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446269/auto-download-and-install-apk-in-android-o), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333602/programatically-find-whether-installing-from-unknown-sources-is-allowed)